# How can I add a last transition to a \texttiming sequence (tikz-timing)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-timing

Given the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-timing}

\begin{document}
\texttiming[X]{1D{A}3D{bar}1D{C}}
\end{document}
```

how can I add a last `D`->`X` transition comparable to the initial `X`->`D` transition?
What I want is to have both ends of the data fields closed, for the first data field, the last data field and every data field in between.

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\begin{document}
\texttiming[X]{1D{A}3D{bar}1D{C}-}
\end{document}
```

#### EDIT

The above solution gives a warning `Package tikz-timing Warning: No transitions 'D-' (or 'D-X') defined!`. Alternate way is to draw using internal `tikzpicture`.

```
\texttiming[X]{1D{A}3D{bar}1D{C}!{-- ++(.1,.5)--++(-0.1,0.5)}}
```

Comment: That gives the warning `Package tikz-timing Warning: No transitions 'D-' (or 'D-X') defined!`

Comment: @apriori try `\texttiming[X]{1D{A}3D{bar}1D{C}0X}`

Comment: `0X` leaves the red transition. `[color=black]0X` does not work either.

Comment: @apriori see the edited answer.